# create two process each having separate terminal to handle all their respective IO operations

Tags: c, linux, terminal, unix-socket

I want to create a **client/server chat application** **in linux/unix** ,in which the client process should basically do this

**process#1** forks to create **process#2**

**process#1 ie. parent process** handles all the client chat input in its separate terminal,and sends those to server,while **process#2(child process)** **ONLY** receives messages from server and outputs them in its own separate terminal.

**Basically parent process and child process must work in parallel in two separate terminals,and must handle all IO operations in their respective separate terminals**

Comment: that means you need to spawn a new terminal. It's not unduable, but you should consider just making 2 executables and starting them each in their own terminals

Comment: Maybe a possible easy solution is : process #2 write in a file and display file in a second terminal. You can have a script to launch at same time client and second terminal which display file content write by process #2

Comment: I'm struggling to understand exactly what you want to do but this question looks much to broad as it stands.  I would point you in the direction of the 'Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment (Third Edition by Stevens and Rago) and especially the chapter on pseudo terminals which I think may be what your after.